# problem with more than 1 level of subitems in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how are you?

I'm using rsuite to do my navigation, but I'm starting to have problems getting past the second level of sub-items in my menu. and actually I'm going to need 4 sublevels.

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong.

the code snippet with menu_options that is commented out is what should be right, but it breaks.

just below it has the menu that works but only with menu and 1 sublevel.

```
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Navbar, Nav} from 'rsuite';

export default function Header(){
  let menu = [
    {name: 'Varejos de Cão', key: 13, subitems: [ // e
      {name: 'Golden',        key: 1, subitems: [ // sub
        {name: 'Raças Pequenas', key: 2, subitems: [ // nvl2
          // {name: 'Adulto Carne', key: 3, link: '/golden_cao_ad_rpq_carne'}, // nvl3
          // {name: 'Adulto Frango', key: 4, link: '/golden_cao_ad_rpq_frango'},
          // {name: 'Filhote Carne', key: 5, link: '/golden_cao_fil_rpq_carne'},
        ]}
      ]}
    ]},
    {name: 'Varejos de Gato', key: 14, subitems: [
      {name: 'Golden',         key: 3, link: '#'}
    ]},
    {name: 'Nossas Lojas', key: 15, subitems: [
      {name: 'Tanque',         key: 6, link: '/tanque'},
      {name: 'Vila Isabel',           key: 7, link: '/vila'},
      {name: 'Grajau',          key: 8, link: '/grajau'},
      {name: 'Pechincha',          key: 9, link: '/pechincha'},
      {name: 'Catete',          key: 10, link: '/catete'},
      {name: 'Jacarepagua',          key: 12, link: '/jacarepagua'},
      {name: 'Tijuca',          key: 11, link: '/tijuca'}
    ]}
  ];

  // let menu_options = menu.map((e, k) => {
  //   let subs = e.subitems.map((nvl1, sub_k) => {
  //     let nvs2 = nvl1.subitems.map((nvl2, sub_k) => {
  //       return(
  //         <Nav.Item className="navigation-item" key={nvl2.key} eventKey={nvl2.key}><NavLink className="header-link" to={nvl2.link}>{nvl2.name}</NavLink></Nav.Item>
  //       );
  //     });

  //     return(
  //       <Nav.Menu title={nvl1.name} key={nvl1.key}>
  //         {nvs2}
  //       </Nav.Menu>
  //     );
  //   });

  //   return(
  //     <Nav.Menu title={e.name} key={k}>
  //       {subs}
  //     </Nav.Menu>
  //   );
  // });

  let menu_options = menu.map((e, k) => {
    let subs = e.subitems.map((sub, sub_k) => {
      return(
        <Nav.Item className="navigation-item" key={sub.key} eventKey={sub.key}><NavLink className="header-link" to={sub.link}>{sub.name}</NavLink></Nav.Item>
      );
    });

    return(
      <Nav.Menu title={e.name} key={e.key}>
        {subs}    
      </Nav.Menu>
    );
  });

  return(
    <div id="page-header">
      <nav id="menu-desktop">
        <div id="header-menu">
          <Navbar>
            <Navbar.Brand href="#">Dogão Pet Shop Varejos</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="header-navigation">
              {/* <Nav.Item eventKey="1" href="/home">Home</Nav.Item> */}
              {menu_options}
            </Nav>
          </Navbar>
        </div>
      </nav>
      {/* <nav id="menu-mobile">
        <div id="header-menu">
          <Navbar>
            <Nav className="header-navigation">
              <Nav.Menu title="Menu">
                <Nav.Item className="navigation-item" eventKey="1"><NavLink className="header-link" to="/home">Home</NavLink></Nav.Item>
                {menu_options}
              </Nav.Menu>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar>
        </div>
      </nav> */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

the error it gives is that you cannot map unknown on line 31

Comment: Not all your elements have a `subitems` property (_"Golden"_ for example). Use optional-chaining to safely iterate optional arrays... `e.subitems?.map(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Map each level (easy to style)

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
function App() {
  let menu = [
    {name: 'Varejos de Cão', key: 13, subitems: [ // e
      {name: 'Golden',        key: 1, subitems: [ // sub
        {name: 'Raças Pequenas', key: 2, subitems: [ // nvl2
          // {name: 'Adulto Carne', key: 3, link: '/golden_cao_ad_rpq_carne'}, // nvl3
          // {name: 'Adulto Frango', key: 4, link: '/golden_cao_ad_rpq_frango'},
          // {name: 'Filhote Carne', key: 5, link: '/golden_cao_fil_rpq_carne'},
        ]}
      ]}
    ]},
    {name: 'Varejos de Gato', key: 14, subitems: [
      {name: 'Golden',         key: 3, link: '#'}
    ]},
    {name: 'Nossas Lojas', key: 15, subitems: [
      {name: 'Tanque',         key: 6, link: '/tanque'},
      {name: 'Vila Isabel',           key: 7, link: '/vila'},
      {name: 'Grajau',          key: 8, link: '/grajau'},
      {name: 'Pechincha',          key: 9, link: '/pechincha'},
      {name: 'Catete',          key: 10, link: '/catete'},
      {name: 'Jacarepagua',          key: 12, link: '/jacarepagua'},
      {name: 'Tijuca',          key: 11, link: '/tijuca'}
    ]}
  ]
  return (
    <div>
      {menu.map((ele1) => (
        <div key={ele1.name}>
          {ele1?.name}
          {ele1?.subitems?.map((ele2) => (
            <div key={ele2.key}>
              {ele2?.name}
              {ele2?.subitems?.map((ele3) => (
                <div key={ele3.key}>
                  {ele3?.name}
                  {ele3?.subitems?.map((ele4) => (
                    <div key={ele4.key}>
                      {ele4?.name}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

2. Recall same renderer (more redable)

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
function App() {
  let menu = [
    {name: 'Varejos de Cão', key: 13, subitems: [ // e
      {name: 'Golden',        key: 1, subitems: [ // sub
        {name: 'Raças Pequenas', key: 2, subitems: [ // nvl2
          {name: 'Adulto Carne', key: 3, link: '/golden_cao_ad_rpq_carne'}, // nvl3
          {name: 'Adulto Frango', key: 4, link: '/golden_cao_ad_rpq_frango'},
          {name: 'Filhote Carne', key: 5, link: '/golden_cao_fil_rpq_carne'},
        ]}
      ]}
    ]},
    {name: 'Varejos de Gato', key: 14, subitems: [
      {name: 'Golden',         key: 3, link: '#'}
    ]},
    {name: 'Nossas Lojas', key: 15, subitems: [
      {name: 'Tanque',         key: 6, link: '/tanque'},
      {name: 'Vila Isabel',           key: 7, link: '/vila'},
      {name: 'Grajau',          key: 8, link: '/grajau'},
      {name: 'Pechincha',          key: 9, link: '/pechincha'},
      {name: 'Catete',          key: 10, link: '/catete'},
      {name: 'Jacarepagua',          key: 12, link: '/jacarepagua'},
      {name: 'Tijuca',          key: 11, link: '/tijuca'}
    ]}
  ]
  const NavRenderer = ({ navEle }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {navEle?.name}
        {navEle?.subitems?.map((ele) => (
          <NavRenderer key={ele.key} navEle={ele} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {menu.map((ele1) => (
        <NavRenderer key={ele1.key} navEle={ele1} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```